# Can you start a matlabpool/parpool on windows in low priority?

Tags: matlab, wmic

On R2013a and Win 7 64bit and i5 3rd gen cpu, the following starts a pool of 4 workers:

```
matlabpool 4
```

which you can see in the task manager among the processes:

[image]

Now, I know how to start MATLAB in [low priority from a shortcut](http://lifehacker.com/5546429/lower-task-priorities-in-windows-to-avoid-slowdowns), and I adopted this approach thinking that the workers would **inherit** the same priority, but they get *normal* by default.

Do you know how to start a matlabpool in **low** priority?

Comment: You could use a vba-script to set the priority of all running `matlab.exe` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393587(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @DanielR I was looking maybe for some undocumented feature within MATLAB  itself.

Comment: have you considered using this: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/1841-priority ?

Comment: @natan Thanks! Interesting submission, which can simplify the wrapper for matlabpool I was thinking to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could combine @natan's suggestion in the comment to use [this file exchange submission](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/1841-priority) in conjunction with a `poolStartup.m` file. See [the doc](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/distcomp/poolstartup.html) for more about how to use `poolStartup.m`.

Answer (score 1):

I created a project-specific `poolStartup.m` script, after [Edric's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20259808/2180721), which lowers the priority of the workers.

The syntax to **start the pool** is the following:

```
matlabpool('open', 4, 'AttachedFiles',{'path\poolStartup.m'})
```

where `poolStartup.m` will contain a [`system()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/system.html) call to WMIC, the Windows Management Instrumentation Command utility.
For more info on usage and examples read [The Grammar of WMIC](http://isc.sans.edu/diary/The+Grammar+of+WMIC/2376), the synopsis [WMIC.exe](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) or the official docs for which the [Win32_Process class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the one of interest here.

I opted for the following call to **lower the priority** (broken down in several lines for exposition):

```
pid    = feature('getpid');
cmdstr = sprintf('wmic process where processid="%d" CALL setpriority 64', pid)
system(cmdstr)
```

The interesting part is:

```
'wmic process where processid="PID" CALL setpriority 64'
```

A few notes:

- Surfing I often found the clause `where name="name.exe"`. While calling `where name="MATLAB.exe"` would lower all the processes with that name at once, i.e. workers and client, that might not be the desired effect. For example, I might want to retain normal priority on the client.
- The well-known but [undocumented `feature()` function](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/undocumented-feature-function/) is called on each worker, thus returning its specific PID.
- The `SetPriority` method of the `Win32_Process` class maps the value 64 to *"idle"*, and does not have a value for the task manager's entry *"low"*. A very quick check shows that the priority queried with `wmic` after setting the process to *"idle"* or *"low"* through the task manager is the same.
- I avoided compilable solutions because the vast majority of MATLAB users are still a bit vary of mexing with that stuff (pun intended).

Comment: One may also use commands, suggested here, in conjunction with "isempty(getCurrentWorker)" to determine, "if running on worker", and/or with "parfevalOnAll()". This provides some additional flexibility, like being able to lower the priority anytime.